# Table header to stay fixed at the top when scrolling

Tags: php, jquery, css, html-table

I am trying to design an HTML table where the header will stay fixed at the top of the page while scrolling down, but it is not working. Below is my html code....

```
<table align="center">
<?php               
$select = "SELECT * FROM register where r_bid='".$_SESSION["id"]."' order by `name` ";
$result = mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());
$res = mysql_query("select * from regi_balic where b_id='".$_SESSION["id"]."'");
$row1=mysql_fetch_array($res);
$i=1;
echo'<thead><tr align="center">
<th width=3%><font size=3><strong>No.</strong></font></th>
<th width=10%><font size=3><strong>IC</strong></font></th>
<th width=12%><font size=3><strong>Name</strong></font></th>
<th width=12%><font size=3><strong>Reference</strong></font></th>
<th width=2%><font size=3><strong>Age</strong></font></th>
<th width=12%><font size=3><strong>Occupatin</strong></font></th>
<th width=5%><font size=3><strong>Mobile No</strong></font></th>
<th width=2%><font size=3><strong>Delete</strong></font></th>
</tr></thead>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   
echo '<tbody><tr>
<td width="3%" align="center" ><font size=3>'.$i.'</font></td>
<td width="10%"><font size=3>'.$row1['name'].'</font></td>
<td width="12%" align="left" ><font size=3>
<a href="edit_detail.phpid='.$row["r_id"].'
&cand_id='.$_SESSION["id"].'&email='.$row["email"].'">'.$row['name'].'</a></font></td>
<td width="12%" align="center" ><font size=3>'.$row['reference'].'</font></td>
<td width="2%" align="right" style="padding-right:8px" >
<fontsize=3>'.$row['age'].'</font></td>
<td width="12%" align="right" style="padding-right:8px"><font 
size=3>'.$row['occupation'].'</font></td>
<td width="5%" align="right"><font size=3>'.$row['mob_no'].'</font></td>
<td width="2%"><a href="process_del_client.php?id='.$row['r_id'].'" onClick="return  
ConfirmSubmit(\'Are You sure ?\')"><img src = "images/delete.png"></a></td>
</tr></tbody>';
$i++;
}
echo '</table></div></center>';                 
?>
</div>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
.list {
height: 409px;
width: 80%;
overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: make thead css position:fixed/absolute.

Comment: add style position:fixed for your table header.

Comment: i hav done this, but thead is overwriting the first row.

Comment: thead{
 position:fixed;
 width: 78%;
 
}

Comment: i have added this to thead

Comment: Can we see the actual HTML output as a jsfiddle.net please.  Makes it much easier to hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? http://jsbin.com/fekoyi/1/edit

```
table {
  height: 1000px; /* To force existence of a scrollbar. */
  background: yellow; /* To aid seeing boundaries. */
}

th {
  position: fixed; /* Fixes its position to the window. */
  top: 0; /* Sets that fixed position to stick to the top of the window. */
  width: 100%; /* Fills the width of the window; made it easier to see in your markup. */
  background: pink; /* To aid seeing boundaries. */
}
```

Comment: still facing the same problem, now the thead sticks at the top of the page, & if i am trying to give the css style as top:100px; to thead, then it again over writes the first row

Comment: Your question asks for "an HTML table where the header will stay fixed at the top of the page while scrolling down." But now you don't want a table-header that "sticks at the top of the page"? Where do you want the table's header?

Comment: my meaning was that the table header should be fixed at its position, and rows should scroll down